# Simulate a click in my webview

Tags: android, webview, simulation

In my application i would like to simulate a click (X,Y) in my webView.
I don't find the response.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by executing a JavaScript function simulating the click inside your webview.[This](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/) might give you an idea on how to execute JavaScript inside webview.

Comment: this link is broken at this moment, can you fix that please, thanks